# Unable to view desktop Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu

I unable to view anything in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I Googled and found `apt-get gnome-panel` may work but I am unable to connect to Internet without top panel. Tried using some commands in `tty1` but it didn’t work. Will installing any other display manager like kdm etc. will solve my problem?

Comment: thanks JakeGould I am just panicked tommorow have to show my project and Ubuntu broke down..

Comment: Well I re-installed Ubuntu and downloaded all necessary things for my project ...Thanks!